# If int n = INT_MIN, why (-n)/2 is positive?

Tags: c++, integer, limit

I've been experimenting with the lowest signed 32-bit integer. I wrote the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>

int main() {
  int n = 1<<31; //-2³¹
  std::cout<<"a) n            = "<< (n)            <<"\n";
  std::cout<<"b) -n           = "<< (-n)           <<"\n";
  std::cout<<"c) -INT_MIN     = "<< (-INT_MIN)     <<"\n"; //-Woverflow printed
  std::cout<<"d) n/2          = "<< (n/2)          <<"\n";
  std::cout<<"e) n/-2         = "<< (n/-2)         <<"\n";
  std::cout<<"f) -n/2         = "<< (-n/2)         <<"\n";
  std::cout<<"g) (-n)/2       = "<< ((-n)/2)       <<"\n";
  std::cout<<"h) (-INT_MIN)/2 = "<< ((-INT_MIN)/2) <<"\n"; //-Woverflow printed
}
```

I compiled it with g++ and got the following output:

```
a) n            = -2147483648
b) -n           = -2147483648
c) -INT_MIN     = -2147483648
d) n/2          = -1073741824
e) n/-2         = 1073741824
f) -n/2         = 1073741824
g) (-n)/2       = 1073741824
h) (-INT_MIN)/2 = -1073741824
```

The first surprise are examples b) and c), showing that `-n` equals `n`, but I understood this: `-n = 2³² - n = 2³¹`, which converted to int becomes `-(2³¹)`.

However, I fail to understand example f). I found that unary minus operator has precedence over division (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). I expected that first `-n` is calculated as `n`, and then `n/2` should be negative, as in example d) – but it is not the case.

I thought that I misunderstood the operator precedence, so I added brackets in example g), but this changed nothing.

And finally, in example h) I changed `n` to `INT_MIN`, which has the same value, but the result of the operation became negative!

What do I miss in understanding examples f) and g)? What is the difference between `n` and `INT_MIN` in this case? Is what I observe specific to the language, or may it depend on the compiler?

Comment: Generally `-INT_MIN` is one more than the largest representable `int`, meaning that everything happening here is undefined behavior.

Comment: `-n` overflows and _"...When signed integer arithmetic operation overflows (the result does not fit in the result type), the behavior is undefined,..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic .  UB in the program makes all the other test useless

Comment: `1 << 31 == 2147483648` which is too large of a value for an `int`, whose max values is `2^31 - 1`

Comment: Read up on two's compliment and you'll probably get a better grip on what you are seeing here.

Comment: Also remember that if you have an equation that has multiple steps if the program breaks in one of the early steps you can't count on a n later operation correcting things. Half of `-INT_MIN` is in range, but `-INT_MIN` broke before it could be divided. This is one of the things that makes testing for overflow tricky. If you test the value for possible overflow AFTER the overflow, the evidence has probably been destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute value of `INT_MIN` is more than the (absolute) value of `INT_MAX`. The operation `-n` produces a result that is outside of representable values when `n == INT_MIN`. When an arithmetic operation on signed integer produces an unrepresentable value, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

Comment: Thanks! Could you confirm whether example e), that is `INT_MIN/-2`, is safe?

Comment: You get unsafety as soon as you try `int n = 1 << 31;` because assuming that `2^31` will wrap around to `-2^31` is actually undefined behavior. If instead you'd done `int n = INT_MIN`, then `(n / -2)` would be defined behavior.

Comment: @NathanPierson `You get unsafety as soon as you try int n = 1 << 31; because assuming that 2^31 will wrap around to -2^31 is actually undefined behavior.` Not anymore, since C++20. It's defined now.

Comment: I thought 2s complement was defined in C++20, but certain operations (such as this one...?) were still undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you referring to the C++20 change requiring that converting from a wider signed integral type to a narrower signed integral type is now required to yield the appropriate result according to modular arithmetic? Afaik nothing has changed the fact that since `1` and `31` are both `int`s, `1 << 31` is integral overflow and hence UB before we even try to assign the result back to an `int`.

Comment: @NathanPierson I'm referring to the rule `The value of E1 << E2 is the unique value congruent to E1×2^E2 modulo 2N, where N is the width of the type of the result.`

Comment: Good catch. Furthermore, apparently [even pre-C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_shift_operators) `1 << 31` was a valid way of getting `INT_MIN`. My earlier comment is therefore mostly incorrect.

Comment: @NathanPierson Hmm, seems so. It seems to be UB in [C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic) though.

Comment: I don't understand this discussion. `1<<31` is a bit operation, sets the oldest bit of a 32 bit variable to 1, there is no assumption on overflowing, only on how bits in a signed integer are interpreted – or is/was that undefined as well?